# Set background color of an item in android listview

Tags: android, listview

We have a androd listview with following adapter code.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);
            } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
  items itm = items.get(position);

  Button stat = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

  holder.items = itm;

  stat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {             
          Intent i = new Intent(context, anotherActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("name", holder.items.getName());
          context.startActivity(i);
      }
  });
  if(itm.getStatus() == 1) {
       convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2dededb"));
       stat.setText("No");
       stat.setEnabled(false);
   }  
  return convertView;
 }
```

The list has several items and we are trying set backgroud color of a particular item based on some flag. But the color is setting randomly.

Comment: you mean also change color of items which not have status 1 ?

Comment: By default there is some color is set in `single_item` xml and it will be changed to other if status is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `color` for other items as well

```
if(itm.getStatus() == 1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f2dededb"));
            stat.setText("No");
            stat.setEnabled(false);
} else {
      convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("//Default color"));
      // Any other code 
}
```

If you are setting `color` for any item on some condition in `ListView`/`Recyclerview` you have to set the `color` for other items as well.(Valid for any other condition as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(itm.getStatus() == 1) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary);

} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorPrimary));
}
```

You can set color according to condition.